# Cannot login to Empathy after setting up Google online account

Tags: empathy, google

On a new installation of 12.10 Ubuntu, have added a Google account for use with Empathy. However, when attempting to connect, Empathy displays "Google Talk Account requires authorisation". Clicking on the icon opens Online Accounts but does not offer an option to perform any further authorisation.

So far have checked the following:

- Seahorse shows two entries for the Google account, one of which lists
  the correct password, the other of which lists a seemingly random
  collection of characters separated by percentage symbols
- Checked Google account, Ubuntu has permission to access: Picasa Web Albums,
  Profile Information, Google Docs, Google Talk
- Google account is not set up to use 2-step verification
- Removed account and seahorse entries, set up from scratch
- If possible, will use non-alphanumeric characters in passwords, so tested with only
  alphanumeric password - no difference
- Not going through a proxy

Activating empathy-debugger shows:

```
wocky/-DEBUG: 21/10/12 11:22:20.784214: _end_element_ns: Received stanza
* failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'
    * not-authorized
    * missing-username xmlns='google:auth'
wocky/-DEBUG: 21/10/12 11:22:20.784320: auth_failed: wocky-sasl-auth.c:274: Authentication failed!: Authentication failed: not-authorized
gabbleauthentication-DEBUG: 21/10/12 11:22:20.784421: gabble_server_sasl_channel_fail (server-sasl-channel.c:929): auth failed: WOCKY_AUTH_ERROR_FAILURE (#6): Authentication     failed: not-authorized
gabbleconnection-DEBUG: 21/10/12 11:22:20.784534: connector_error_disconnect (connection.c:1760): Interactive authentication error, reason 3, dbus error org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Error.AuthenticationFailed
```

So, it seems that seahorse has the correct password in place, and the Google account is set up in such a way as to allow the application to work. That being the case, it makes no sense to be getting an authorisation error, unless there is something else that isn't immediately obvious.

Have checked for open bugs here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bugs
- https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=telepathy

However nothing that matched this exact problem jumped out - a lot of issues seem to be with 2-step verification (but as mentioned earlier this has not been enabled).

Is there anything else to try at this point?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Many thanks, have filed a bug here as requested: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/1069531

Answer (score 2):

After further ivestigation, confirmed the issue was caused by the account itself.

Although chat from Google+ was possible when logged into the account in Firefox, the account associated with the non-gmail address started life as a youtube account, hence it had never been connected to a gmail account. This seems to be a requirement, see also:

http://support.google.com/talk/answer/141360?hl=en

https://superuser.com/questions/444262/using-google-talk-with-a-non-apps-non-gmail-google-account

So, added a gmail account, removed it and re-established the non-gmail account as the primary login.
Can now sign in to Empathy properly.

Tested by sending an invite to a second gmail account not already displayed in the G+ chat list of online users. This worked properly and could send message back and forth as expected.

Initially, all of the existing G+ contacts showed as offline (which they were not - the second gmail account had a contact that was visible to both accounts and could see that contact fine).

Problem later resolved itself:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=182084

"It can take up to 10 minutes for a new primary email address to be reflected throughout the system, 24 hours for domain and personal contact changes to take effect, and up to 3 days before the user can use Google Talk."